# Create time stamp for updated in SQL, without doing a inner join on ID number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a trigger on MSSMS that generates a last update time stamp everytime somebody updates a row.

The usual solution I found around here is pretty straight forward:

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.SetLastUpdatedBusiness 
ON dbo.Businesses 
AFTER UPDATE -- not insert!
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT UPDATE(LastUpdated)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE t
            SET t.LastUpdated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -- not dbo.LastUpdated!
            FROM dbo.Businesses AS t -- not b!
            INNER JOIN inserted AS i 
            ON t.ID = i.ID;
    END
END
GO
```

But the tables I am working with do not have an ID column to do a inner join on. Is there any other way to do it if you do not have an ID column?

Thanks.

EDIT: I got some advice to add an ID column to the table, and then I can do the inner join.

Comment: Don't they have some possible combination of values that makes a row unique, even if it's not defined as a primary key?

Comment: Do they have primary key column, a column(s) which uniquely identify a row? If yes, then use those in your inner join

Comment: Please show us the table structure

Comment: How exactly are you updating the row of data? From a stored proc or within some application code?

Comment: You should have some way to uniquely identify the rows in your table. If you don't have any value (or combination of values) that is unique per row, your data model is broken.

Comment: @Rigierta Demiri I doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Zohar Peled I understand what you mean. There are two tables, one with the ID code, and one that went through ETL without it.